# Adding Touch Hotspots for App Store Video

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, imovie

I am trying to figure out how to add touch hotspots to screen recording videos so I can use the videos for the App Store so people can see how to use the app and make the videos easier to understand. There are surprisingly there are barely any information on this on Google. I screen record myself using the app then I use iMovie to edit and add captions. If any one knows how to do this please help out.

P.S. touch hotspots are the circles (usually blue) on a screen recording video that shows where the user is tapping.